# object detection model - tensorflow served - k8s deployed : takes long time 3-4 seconds

Tags: azure, tensorflow, kubernetes, tensorflow-serving, azure-aks

I have a TensorFlow object detection model, served with TensorFlow serving and deployed into the Azure Kubernetes cluster. I have used Nvidia K80 GPU device, with TensorFlow/serving:1.12.3:gpu version.

The model is deployed and response properly, but the response time is huge, 3-4 seconds for 500*375 - 135 KB images.

Can anyone help me to understand what can be improved?

Comment: Could be the resources that the k8s cluster has. I have experienced a few similar things and when I upped the cpu count and memory available to the post on the k8s cluster, performance significantly improved. As stated in the answer given, the first request usually takes longer, but then the following requests should be a fair amount faster.

Answer (score 0):

If this image is the first prediction request, it is a normal situation. You may need a warm-up request.

Comment: i tested with 20 images , the average response time is 2-3 seconds.